# jQuery | How to grab the first available class with the given selectors?

Tags: jquery

Okay, so this code looks for these two classes on another page and appends them to a single div on another page. How do I set the code so that if ".blog-post img" is found and appended, then "blog-post .youtube" will not be found and appended, and vice versa?

In other words, I want the code to look for and grab the first class (i.e., .blog-post img) on the other page if it's available, if not, look for and grab the second class (.blog-post .youtube).

```
    <script>
    $("document").ready(function(){
            $.get('/blog.html', function(data){ 
                $(data).find(".blog-post img, .blog-post .youtube").appendTo(".post-title-1");
            });
     });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add more classes if you like and no more code will be needed.

```
$($(data).find(".blog-post img, .blog-post .youtube")[0]).appendTo(".post-title-1");
```

Comment: Simple, beautiful, exactly what I needed! Thank you very much, @artemisian!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
        $.get('/blog.html', function(data){ 
            var output = $(data).find(".blog-post img") || $(data).find(".blog-post .youtube"); // if ".blog-post img" fails then use ".blog-post .youtube"
            $(".post-title-1").append(output);
        });
 });
```

`var a = b || c;`

Using the above JS shorthand we can apply an object (b) to a variable (a), and if that variable is `''` or `undefined` or `null` then default to a further object (c) using the 'or' operator `||`.

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.